# How to put an image over background colour?

Tags: css

Hello we are using CSS3.

We have a TD tag and it has background color set to red.

We are looking for a way in which we can put an image that is centered over that red background. Both red background and centered image must be visible within the td tag.

The background and image must be specified in inline style of the TD tag..

Comment: plz share the html and css code..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML:

```
<td style="background: red url(http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-50-50-9.jpg) center no-repeat"></td>
```

[Background](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background) property docs.

1. `red` sets `background-color`
2. `url(...)` sets image
3. `center` sets image origin to center
4. `no-repeat` disables image repeating

[image]

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/yoviboji/2/edit?html,css,output).

Answer (score 3):

using background property we can do it

try following

```
background: url("image path") no-repeat scroll center center #FF0000;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show the background color as well add a width and height to your td tag and a background size to your image like the following CSS.

```
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background-color: red;
background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7woY.png?s=128&g=1');
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100px 100px;
```